# Sublime text 3 is working weirdly when I try coding it in html

Tags: html, css, sublimetext3, flexbox

I was using Sublime Text 3 to write a HTML document but when I started to write `<!DOCTYPE html>` Sublime auto-filled it to `<!DOCTYPE <!DOCTYPE html>`, I cannot understand why? If I write `<!DOCTYPE html>` then flexbox layout doesn't work. 
Any ideas?

Comment: I know it is <!DOCTYPE> but when i was putting arrow brackets i was not able to post my question

Answer (score 0):

Hitting `tab` after `html` is a shortcut when typing up HTML documents in Sublime Text.
It expands to:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: my code is expanded to <!DOCTYPE <!DOCTYPE html>? & why is the flexbox layout not working after I remove the extra <!DOCTYPE ?

Comment: That's because you manually typed `<!DOCTYPE html` then pressed tab. So it expanded to `<!DOCTYPE <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>`. As for the flexbox, look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k0jdL5rk/2/) - the code is from [mozilla dev guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes#Basic_flex_example).

Answer (score 0):

Press the opening tag `<` and then type `html` after that press `tab` button it will generate the code. For example

`<html +tab`

It will generate this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
  </html>
```